# Tag-sorting in the review queues

Tags: support

As I currently write there are 100 odd questions to be reviewed in the close-vote queue. This is quite a lot, and it seems to me that reviewers are highly unlikely to try and clear this queue in one go. It's a bit like sitting down to a meal that's obvioulsy way to big for you. It kind of puts you off. We obviously want reviewers to be making careful and considered judgements, and often this means taking sufficient time and care to read questions closely and perhaps do some research.

Now, I'm not equally interested in all the questions on the site here. One word wonder questions are my pet hate. It's therefore extremely difficult for me to review such questions objectively or with equanimity. I therefore skip nearly all W3 questions unless I can make an instant decision. Anything that requires more that a second's thought triggers an automatic reflex skip command to my hand.

On the other hand, when I see a syntax question, I am much more able to give it calm and considered attention. I'm pretty sure there are users here who have the inverse response to these categories of question and who could quite happily sift through W3 questions for hours but go green at the mention of an auxiliary verb.

Would it be possible to add a feature to the review queues so that we could filter them by tag? It seems to me that this would make the process much more efficient as users will be focussing on areas that interest them. Offending questions are going to get shorter shrft and better ones and ones with more potential will be considered by people who are more interested in those particular areas and would have more time to properly asses them.

What do you guys think?

Comment: There are already filters in place. EDIT: Didn't see Matt's answer for some reason, when I commented. Oh well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already exists!

[image: filter for tags and close reason types]

Comment: Although filters do not guarantee that SWR will be omitted. If I VTC a SWR as a duplicate, Araucaria will still see that post in his review queue. Likewise, a question on pure 100% grammar might be flagged as a duplicate too. And sometimes SWR are "off topic" b/c they lack research, or they are POB...

Comment: Ahh, you can write tags in the box. I hadn't noticed that. Duh

Comment: How does a question get put in that queue? Because 1 person voted to close already?

Comment: @Mitch > Questions with active close votes or close flags show up in the close queue [metameta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/147791)

Comment: @Mari-LouA so a default one should be single-word-request